# Execute the same code on blur and enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am having a bit of trouble to execute the samecode on blur() and on the key enter. I use the following code:

```
 $(".formatted-date").bind('blur keyup',function(e) {  
    if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == '13') { 
        console.log("action fired");
    }
});
```

But when I use this implementation then within the console window of the browser I get the following error message:

> jquery.js:3 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on
>   'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node.
>   Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?(…)

Is there an alternative way of creating a function that will be executed on blur and the "enter" key?

Comment: Have you tried to remove all listeners before adding new one?
try this $(".formatted-date").off();

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly as shown below,The error you are getting seems to be because you are trying to append a child to a node which has already been removed

```js
 $(".formatted-date").bind('blur keyup',function(e) {  
   console.log("asdfs")
    if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == '13') { 
        console.log("action fired");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="formatted-date"/>
```

Comment: But that is weird because the div is never removed from the DOM. Any ideas what I could do to debug it?

Comment: do you have a fiddle ,code pen of our code? then we can check it directly there

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as intended, see snippet.
Make sure you've got an up to date jQuery version too.

```js
$("#test").bind('blur keyup',function(e) {  
    if (e.type == 'blur' || e.keyCode == '13') { 
        console.log("action fired");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
```

Comment: But I use the latest version of jQuery of the 1 series. jQuery versie 1.12

Comment: can you post more of the relevant code? there's nothig wrong with the bit you posted. give us the html, and whatever js does things to it

Comment: I found out that the code is indeed working perfectly but it causing weird behaviour in my jQuery DatePicker. For some reason it is creating an extra input field with datepicker functionality. So I am going to ask another question because posting it here will be a bit off topic and it is a totally different problem

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`?